# How is R option "max.print" quantified?

Tags: r, data-structures, console

R output to the console is controlled by the "max.print" option, and large objects are truncated to this number, with excess entries omitted. The documentation for `?options` states:

> `max.print`:
>
> integer, defaulting to 99999. print or show methods can
>   make use of this option, to limit the amount of information that is
>   printed, to something in the order of (and typically slightly less
>   than) `max.print` *entries*.

But I can't find an exact definition of "*entries*". It's not measured in characters, but seems to control:

1. Vector or list elements
2. Dataframe or matrix rows
3. Lines of text from function outputs

This makes the option somewhat unpredictable when trying to plan output sizes (for example, when `sink`ing console output to a file). To exert more control, it would help to know what constitute "*entries*" for a given `print` call. Presumably, this is defined from the data structure passed to `print`... is there a definition for what constitutes an "entry" for all data structures?

Comment: would it be possible for you to use `write()` instead of `sink'? The print _man page_ states ``For more customizable (but cumbersome) printing, see `cat`, `format` or also `write`.'' (`?print`)

Comment: Unfortunately, no - I'm specifically trying to pipe the output from a command directly to a file, and `sink()` is, to my knowledge, the only way to do this. If I were working with character vectors, `write()` would suit, but I can't coerce my output into a character vector without dramatically damaging its readability.

Comment: Maybe it's worth going in your process upstream and asking a new question about how to output the kinda data you have.

Comment: If I need to repeat this task with a larger dataset, then definitely, yes! And I've marked that down in my code for future self-reference. For the current dataset, `sink()` with `options("max.print"=.Machine$integer.max)` got the job done for me. The question of how R defines "entries" to `max.print` is more curiosity-driven than needs-driven at this point.

Comment: Sounds smart. My curiosity is also onto that question now. Please ping me if you find the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of curiosity, I've pulled up the source code for `max.print`. I believe this part of it is written in `Fortran`. Its all greek to me but this is the literal guts of it.

```
    else if (streql(CHAR(namei), "max.print")) {
    int k = asInteger(argi);
    if (k < 1) error(_("invalid value for '%s'"), CHAR(namei));
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(value, i, SetOption(tag, ScalarInteger(k)));
    }
```

If you would like to look at the full source code for `options` it can be found here. https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/options.c

Comment: Good call in going back to the source. This is one of the `C` family - also greek to me (if it were `Fortran` I'd stand some chance). I'm loving the comments, though; line 427: '[ Vomits quietly onto shoes ... ]`.

Comment: Given my poor grasp of `C`, here's my interpretation: Before line1 here, there's an `if` about arguments to `options` in "list" or "paired" format. Given that the argument isn't in list format (hence `else`), it must be a pair of arguments: `namei` = "max.print", `argi` = the number we specified at `options`. So, to roughly parse C to English: "if the `namei` argument coerces to a character string matching "max.print" (in other words, "if this is a call to max.print"), then set integer variable `k` equal to "argi". `k` can't be less than 1 - if so, give an error - then `SET_VECTOR_ELT...`

Comment: `SET_VECTOR_ELT` seems to be some internally defined function, perhaps pulled from one of the include files called at this script's initialization. Assuming that it's used to define a vector, it seems to be saying "call the `SetOption` function for `tag` (which I assume corresponds to "max.print" somehow), and set vector `value` for iteration `i` to the integer value of `k`. _If that's true_ (know anyone who codes in `C`?) then the "max.print" call is setting the size of the vector that can be printed on the console. However, that doesn't explain all of the odd behaviour we've been seeing...

Comment: I don't know anyone off the top of my head. Maybe just ask it as another question and tag `C`. Please post link here though if you do. Given the behavior of the console displaying `n+1` when the number of entries is `n+1`and the console displaying `n` when the number of entries is `>n+2`, I suspect it has something to do with `k<1`. Just a shot in the dark. Could change it to `k=<1`recompile and see if there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

trial and knowledge,

```
options(max.print = 20)

( forty <- 1:40 ) 
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
#> [19] 19 20
#>  [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 20 entries ]

( A = matrix(forty, nrow=10, ncol=4, byrow = TRUE) )
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#>  [1,]    1    2    3    4
#>  [2,]    5    6    7    8
#>  [3,]    9   10   11   12
#>  [4,]   13   14   15   16
#>  [5,]   17   18   19   20
#>  [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 5 rows ]

as.data.frame(A)
#>    V1 V2 V3 V4
#> 1   1  2  3  4
#> 2   5  6  7  8
#> 3   9 10 11 12
#> 4  13 14 15 16
#> 5  17 18 19 20
#>  [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 5 rows ]

require(tibble)
as_tibble(A)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>       V1    V2    V3    V4
#>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1      1     2     3     4
#> 2      5     6     7     8
#> 3      9    10    11    12
#> 4     13    14    15    16
#>  [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 6 rows ]
```

As Keegan Smith [points out below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815219/how-is-r-option-max-print-quantified/46815779?noredirect=1#comment80581163_46815779) the fuzziness can be illustrated clearly like this

```
options(max.print = 5); c(1:10); c(1:6)
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#> [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 5 entries ]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

i.e. `max.print` is fuzzy in the limit.

Comment: Sure, but R's a programming language, so there must be a rule defining this behaviour. Determining everything by trial is tedious, and sets up potential inductive fallacies when unexpected behaviour arises - for example, `options("max.print"=20); c(1:40)` returns 20 elements, but `c(1:21)` returns 21 elements.

Comment: Agree; the behavior is diffidently defined defined somewhere. I simply took a pragmatic approach.

Comment: Fair enough; another pragmatic approach to this problem would be to set `options("max.print"=.Machine$integer.max)` (well, pragmatic in this case, since I know my output won't be large enough to cause problems). I have no problem with workarounds, I'd just like to know how this works under the hood!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be the limit of character, numeric or logical counts, i.e. the `length()` of a object.

```
options(max.print = 10) #Set max.print to 10

test<-1:100 #test1
test
test2<-101:200 #test2
test2
letters #test3
test4<-c("test1","test2","test3","test4","test5","test6","test7","test8","test9","test10","test11,"test12","test13") #test4
test4
data.frame(cbind(test,test2)) #test5
test==test2 #Test6
```

Comment: You've got a typo in `test4` - the "test11" string needs closing quotes. In any case, this seems to be true for vectors. For matrices and dataframes, with `options("max.print"=maxn")`, the return seems to be truncated by `floor(maxn/ncol(df))`, and `ncol(df)==length(df)`. I guess this is because a partial row can't be returned.

Comment: Also, here's an exception: `options("max.print"=10)` `stringvector2=c("R","hello","world","foo","bar","my","hovercraft","is","full","of","eels")` has length 11, but `stringvector2` returns `[1] "R" "hello" "world" "foo" "bar" "my" "hovercraft" "is" "full" "of" "eels"` - that is, it returns all 11 elements!

Comment: I did notice when you provide 11 characters it returns all 11. Not sure why.

Comment: Seems to do that for all vectors - it does it for c(1:11) as well!

Answer (score 0):

first, write the "options" function like this
options(max.print=1874) # dataset of 1874 rows

second, write the vector/df to print
duplicated(ubi.sf$geometry) # this works for me